# number of tables in database always returns 1

Tags: mysql

everybody is suggesting to use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables`

if I do the following, I always get '1' returned:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) 
                  FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'usr_web275'");
$number_of_tables_in_database=mysql_num_fields($res);
echo $number_of_tables_in_database;
```

Comment: Why are you getting the "num_fields" instead of retrieving the result of the query?

Comment: because im not sure what im doing. what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: If someone told you to use a query, then just get the result of that query. Don't get the number of fields in that query.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'usr_web275'");

//Check if any row is returned or not.
if (!$res) {    
    echo "No data found";
}

else
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);  //Returns the row of the result
    $number_of_tables_in_database = $row["count(*)"];
    echo $number_of_tables_in_database;
}
```